# Android Adapter for 2 Database Sources

Tags: sql, android, cursor

I have 2 Android Databases in my app. For the sake of an example, lets say Database #1 is called JOBS and has the following columns: 
`"Jobs Primary Key" - "Job Title" - "Job Description"`

Database #2 is called PEOPLE and has the following columns: 
`"People Primary Key" - "First Name" - "Last Name" - "Jobs ID Key"`

(Yes I know these are not the greatest of designs from a database perspective, this is just to help paint a picture for my question).

Within a ListView, I'd like to display columns "First Name" - "Last Name" - "Job Title" (1 column from Database #1, 2 columns from Database #2). Using a SimpleCursorAdapter, is it possible to somehow accomplish this?

If I don't use a SimpleCursorAdapter, the only way that I can think to accomplish this is to use an ArrayAdapter, where I use a StringBuilder to concatenate the 3 columns together, and fill the ListView, but I'm wondering if there is a better way to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is possible — assuming you mean two tables in one database, rather than two separate databases.

You just need to query your database to [join](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29) the info from the two tables together.

For example, something (completely untested) like this:

`String[] columns = { "first_name", "last_name", "title" };

SQLiteDatabase db = mDbOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase();

Cursor c = db.query("person LEFT OUTER JOIN job ON person.job_id = job.id", columns, null, null, null, null, null);`

Then you can pass the `Cursor` to the `Adapter` as usual.

Comment: Thanks a lot Christopher, I'll have to give that a try tonight. I'll let you know how it turns out.

Comment: Thanks guys, this did the trick, using LEFT OUTER JOIN. I apologize for the lateness of accepting the answer, I did not get the opportunity to test right away. Thanks Again!

Answer (score 0):

I can't seem to comment, but you'll want to use LEFT OUTER JOIN instead of JOIN (in Christopher's answer) if you want people without jobs to show up too.

Comment: Ah, I did think about that then got lazy. Thanks, I've added it to my answer :)